# JavaCV pass video frame to imread()

Tags: java, opencv, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm trying to use JavaCV for template matching. The demo example is located **[here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/TemplateMatching.java)**. I add all their `.jar` files to the project. I need to pass a video frame (say `video.mp4`'s last frame) to `imread()` instead of it reading the source image from file. How can I do that?

```
String [] arg={"laff.png","template.png"};
FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video.mp4");
System.out.println(grabber.getFrameRate());    //returns 0???

// read in image default colors
Mat sourceColor = imread(args[0]);   // pass last frame of video.mp4 instead of args[0]
```

**UPDATE:** I now can pass [the first] video frame to `imread()` using the following way (key point is to call `start()`). So I got the conversion done. Now I need to know how to grab a particular frame number, say the last frame.

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video.mp4");
grabber.start();
System.out.println(grabber.getLengthInTime());
OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();
```

Comment: Given that `imread` exclusively reads and decodes single images from files, your request (as phrased) doesn't make much sense. Once you've grabbed the desired frame from a video using an appropriate tool (such as `VideoCapture` class), just pass the `Mat` that holds it to your function and use it.

Comment: I got the conversion done. Now I need to know how to grab a particular frame number, say last frame.

Comment: If you are using OpenCV why do you not use the [VideoCapture class](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture.html) and then set the property with the frame you want (you can even say last frame) then just the read function and you get your frame...

Comment: @api55 I couldn't find anything like `getFrame(frame_number)`. Do you mean I should just keep calling `capture.read(frame)` until I reach the end??

Comment: nope, not sure now if it can be done in java, but take a look to the function set. In c++/python you can use [any of the properties](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) and one of them is `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` but in [java it seems to be missing](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html) so no i am not sure if it is possible from java... you can loop until you get there as you suggested